# How does umbraco mix XSLT with C# code

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Take a look at this code:

```
<ul>  
 <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/node">  
 <li><a>
       <xsl:attribute name="href">
          <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:NiceUrl(current()/@id)"/>
       </xsl:attribute> 
       <xsl:value-of select="current()/@nodeName"/>    
     </a>  
 </li>  
 </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

As you can see there are umbraco commands within the xslt. How exactly is this done? How can I put my own C# commands in my xslt?

Comment: How did you decide that there is C# code? This might be Java, VB, C++ or any other PL code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class with public static methods.   Then register your assembly in the XsltExtensions.config file in the config directory.

There is example configuration in the file.

Comment: In the latest version 4.7 you can also register your Class and Methods by decorating your class with attributes [XsltExtension("AliasYouWantToGiveIt")] you dont need to mess with an XML configuration that way.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of approaches for injecting some custom logic. Check it out - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302079.aspx